# Google Map freezes when Ajax refreshes too frequently

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using MarkerClusterer, Overlapping Marker Spiderfier, and markers with labels in my Google Map, as well as updating real-time data using Ajax.

The problem is when I set Ajax to refresh some small amount of time (say 2 sec), the map will freeze and won't respond to pan or zoom, but the markers are still moving and changing.

Why is this happening? I'm using Ruby on rails, by the way. Is it possible I'm using too many scripts? Any suggestions on where to start on fixing this?

Attached is my code and my freezing map:

```
<%= form_tag '/gmaps', :method => :get, :class => "form-search" do %>
  <%= select_tag "project_id", options_for_select(@projects, :selected => @project_id), :prompt => "Select Project" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Filter", :class => "btn" %>
<% end %>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<%= include_gon %>
<link href="/assets/gmaps.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="/assets/marker.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
  <script src="/assets/markerclusterer.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

  <script src="/assets/markerclusterer.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>


 <script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/markerwithlabel.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">

   var marker=[]
   function initMap() {

     var latLng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(1.352083, 103.819836);
     var myOptions = {
         zoom: 12,
         center: latLng1,
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
     }
     var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), myOptions);
     var mcOptions={gridSize: 50,maxZoom: 15};


     var oms = new OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier(map)

     for(i=0;i<gon.astatic.length;i++){


      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(gon.astatic[i][1], gon.astatic[i][2]);
       if(i<gon.vnum){
       marker[i] = new MarkerWithLabel({position: latLng, map: map,icon:"/assets/vibra.png" ,title: gon.astatic[i][4],labelClass: "labelsv",labelContent: gon.astatic[i][3]});}
       else
       {
      marker[i] = new MarkerWithLabel({position: latLng, map: map,icon:"/assets/noise.png" ,title: gon.astatic[i][4],labelClass: "labelsn",labelContent: gon.astatic[i][3]});
       }

       oms.addMarker(marker[i]);


     }

        var stringiw;
    var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,marker,mcOptions); 
    var iw = new google.maps.InfoWindow();




  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 240
  });



         google.maps.event.addListener(mc,"mouseover",function(c){
        var markerc = c.getMarkers();
        var datastring='';
        for( var i=0; i< markerc.length;i++){
    datastring += markerc[i].title ;
        datastring += ' : ';
        datastring += '<font color="#48b5e9">'+markerc[i].labelContent+'</font>';
        datastring += "<br>";
    }

        var content = '<div id="iw-container">' +
                    '<div class="iw-title">Realtime Monitor </div>' +
                    '<div class="iw-content">' +
                      '<div class="iw-subTitle">'+datastring+'</div>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div class="iw-bottom-gradient"></div>' +
                  '</div>';

    infowindow.setContent(content);
    infowindow.setPosition(c.getCenter());
    infowindow.open(map);
    });

   google.maps.event.addListener(mc,'clusterclick',function(){
        infowindow.close();
        });

 // *
  // START INFOWINDOW CUSTOMIZE.
  // The google.maps.event.addListener() event expects
  // the creation of the infowindow HTML structure 'domready'
  // and before the opening of the infowindow, defined styles are applied.
  // *
  google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {


    var iwOuter = $('.gm-style-iw');
    var iwBackground = iwOuter.prev();

    // Removes background shadow DIV
    iwBackground.children(':nth-child(2)').css({'display' : 'none'});

    // Removes white background DIV
    iwBackground.children(':nth-child(4)').css({'display' : 'none'});

    iwBackground.children(':nth-child(3)').find('div').children().css({'box-shadow': 'rgba(72, 181, 233, 0.6) 0px 1px 6px', 'z-index' : '1'});

    var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();

    // Apply the desired effect to the close button
    iwCloseBtn.css({opacity: '1', right: '38px', top: '3px', border: '7px solid #48b5e9', 'border-radius': '13px', 'box-shadow': '0 0 5px #3990B9'});

    // If the content of infowindow not exceed the set maximum height, then the gradient is removed.
    if($('.iw-content').height() < 140){
      $('.iw-bottom-gradient').css({display: 'none'});
    }
    iwCloseBtn.mouseout(function(){
      $(this).css({opacity: '0.7'});
    });
  });

   }

    var ajax_call = function() {

     $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url:"gmaps/updatedata",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(result){
        //result
        //console.log(result);
        for(i=0;i<result.length;i++)
       {
       marker[i].labelContent=result[i];
       marker[i].label.setContent();
       }

        }})
   };
   var interval = 1000*30
   setInterval(ajax_call,interval);
 </script>
</head>

<body onload="initMap()">
<div id="map_canvas" style="width: 945px; height: 700px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: zoom level changed but map background freeze]

[image: This its what it should be]